# Bokeh x_axis_type for time duration?

Tags: python, bokeh

The x-axis on my bokeh plot represents a time duration like `five seconds` rather than a time like `2016-01-01 12:00:00`.  Is there a way to render the ticks on my Bokeh x-axis appropriately?  Setting `x_axis_type='datetime'` doesn't do quite the right thing, as can be seen from the repetition of `0ms` in the plot below:

[image]

Comment: "You should probably make a custom tick formatter" (from @bigreddot via gitter).  Perhaps someone has time to submit a example demonstration as an answer.

Comment: There's an example in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37182788/1736679

Answer (score 1):

On Bokeh 0.12.6, [you can use `PrintfTickFormatter`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.PrintfTickFormatter).

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import PrintfTickFormatter

output_file('output.html')

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400) p.line(x, y, size=1)

# must be applied to the 1st element, not the axis itself 
p.xaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%sms")

show(p)
```

You don't even have to set `x_axis_type='datetime'`, it will work even with a linear axis.

EDIT: To apply custom formatting of units, such as ms/s/min, [you have to use `FuncTickFormatter`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.PrintfTickFormatter), because it is too sophisticated for Bokeh to handle at the moment. There are two ways to use it as of 0.12.6.

First, by using the transpiler to convert a Python function to Javascript code, via [Flexx](https://github.com/zoofIO/flexx) (`pip install flexx`). It keeps everything under the Python syntax, but requires an additional dependence.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import FuncTickFormatter

output_file('output.html')

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400) p.line(x, y, size=1)

# custom formatter function
def custom_formatter():
    units = [
        ('min', 60000.0),
        ('s', 1000.0),
        ('ms', 1.0),
    ]
    for u in units:
        if tick >= u[1]:
            return '{}{}'.format(tick / u[1], u[0])


# must be applied to the 1st element, not the axis itself 
p.xaxis[0].formatter = FuncTickFormatter.from_py_func(custom_formatter)

show(p)
```

Lastly, by writing actual Javascript code as a string and passing as a parameter to the formatter. Bokeh does it natively. Bear in mind you have no control over the client environment, so avoid using anything other than pure vanilla Javascript.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import FuncTickFormatter

output_file('output.html')

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400) p.line(x, y, size=1)

units = [
        ('min', 60000.0),
        ('s', 1000.0),
        ('ms', 1.0),
    ]

# must be applied to the 1st element, not the axis itself 
p.xaxis[0].formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code=""" var units = {'min':
60000.0, 's': 1000.0, 'ms': 1.0}; for (u in units) {
    if (tick >= units[u]) {
        return (tick / units[u] + u);
    } } """)

show(p)
```

I find it a bit annoying, but that's how I fixed the axis for my application. I find the need to hardcode a variable named `tick` a terrible programming practice. Hopefully, Bokeh will provide a better solution in the near future.

Comment: This is great.  Any thoughts on how to handle datetime units, like when things go from millseconds to seconds or minutes?

Comment: @MRocklin Yes, I have had a similar issue for my application as well (I deal with days/months/years, however). I have edited the question to add the solution I ended up using, although it was a lot more _hacky_ than I had desired.